# vbscript Excel Match Function

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a worksheet with some 100k rows by perhaps 2 dozen columns. Presently I am coloring a specific column, say "ABC", that when the value is > x set the interior.colorindex to y. At the moment I have to sort this column descending, then using a FOR EACH statement, cycle through each of the row cells until the value < x, coloring the cell as each NEXT is reached.

What I am trying to be is make this far more efficient by using the Excel MATCH function, find the last row number, then color the cells in one block rather than individual cells but cannot get my clumsy coding to work correctly. Everything I have read appears to indicate that the MATCH function is supported in vbscript, but I need some assistance from some kind soul figure this out. I have trimed my code down to the relevant section and would appreciate and assistance provided. Please forgive my ignorance, I am very new to this coding thing, and this is my first post requesting help.

```
Dim objXLApp, objXLWb, objXLWs, objWorksheet, WorksheetFunction
Dim InFile, OutFile
Dim ObjRange, ObjRange2, ObjRange3, rng, rng1, rng2, trng
Dim iRows, iCols, iR, iC, lRow, fRow, col, rw, tRow
Dim ColSearch, StartTime, EndTime, TotalTime
Dim cTeal, cPurple, cCyan, cVal, opVal
Dim Counttcolor, Countpcolor, Countccolor, clr
Dim vMsg 

' input parameters
InFile = Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)
OutFile = Wscript.Arguments.Item(1) 'this output file CAN be the same as the input thereby overwriting if required.

Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'application function SWITCHES - set to TRUE to enable
objXLApp.Visible          = True
objXLApp.EnableEvents     = True
objXLApp.DisplayAlerts    = True
objXLApp.ScreenUpdating   = True
objXLApp.DisplayStatusBar = False
vMsg = 1 ' set to 1 to turn on timer prompts for each processing section

Set objXLWb = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open(InFile)

'Select the appropriate Sheet in the Workbook
Set objXLWs = objXLWb.Sheets(1)

objXLWb.Sheets(1).Activate
objXLWs.DisplayPageBreaks = False

'decleration must be AFTER opening the input file
objXLApp.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 
objXLApp.CalculateBeforeSave = True

' Set range and count Row & Columns
Set objRange = objXLWs.UsedRange
iRows = objRange.Rows.Count
iCols = objRange.Columns.Count
'MsgBox iRows
'MsgBox iCols

StartTime = Timer()
ColSearch = "ABC" 'COLUMN AS
For iC = 1 To iCols
    If InStr(objRange.Item(1, iC).Value2,ColSearch) Then
        'sort the column descending to bring highest records to the top
        Set objRange = objXLWs.UsedRange
        Set objRange2 = objXLApp.Range(objRange.Item(2, iC).Address) 'ABC
        objRange.Sort objRange2, xlDescending, , , , , , xlYes

        cTeal = 15 'set the teal minimum value

        'set the range for the match function to search for the min cTeal value
        rng = objRange.Item(2, iC).Address &":"& objRange.Item(iRows, iC).Address 
        'search for the first row number containing the first value less than cTeal
        tRow = objXLApp.match(cTeal, rng, -1)
        MsgBox tRow 'this presently fails here with object required if commented fails at set trng with reference to tRow variable

        'set the range for coloring the entire block of cells
        Set trng = objRange.Item(2, iC).Address &":"& objRange.Item(tRow, iC).Address
        objXLApp.Range(trng).Interior.ColorIndex = 42 'Teal
    End If
Next

EndTime = Timer()
If vMsg = 1 Then MsgBox "ABC: " & FormatNumber(EndTime - StartTime, 2)
```

Comment: The Excel-builtin feature you're trying to replicate here is called "conditional formatting".

Comment: Thought of that, but thanks for the suggestion. Problem here is I have to do this via command line external to Excel and requirements are that I cannot distribute the resulting file with conditional formatting enabled in the file I am afraid. I was previously looking for a way to use Conditional Formatting in a template file, but could not figure out how to remove the CF rules but leave formatted resulting cells. Have tried copy and pasting special but cannot get that to work either, always seems to bring the rules, cannot get just the values and color.

Comment: What I am trying to avoid is cycling through the entire 100K rows, I presently HAVE to until I reach the less than value at which point I note the row and use rowcount to color the last range, but it is the greater than 15 and between 14 and say 9 that I cannot establish the range addresses without using something like Match to do so.

Comment: What I was hoping I could do was issue say 3 or 4 match commands to establish the range row numbers then color the cells by range block, rather than individually which obviously takes the time.

Comment: Hmmm .. just a thought, I a wondering if because I have turned off Automatic Calculation, whether that is causing the problem? Will have to check when I can get to the office.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, it was a range issue. Needed to set the range to a single column (ie: A:A and not the cell references as existed) but I had something wrong in my existing code. Thanks anyway.

For reference sake, here is the working code:

```
ColSearch = "ABC"
For iC = 1 To iCols
    If InStr(objRange.Item(1, iC).Value2,ColSearch) then

        'to get the column letter for setting the rng param for match function
        col_letter = Split(objRange.Item(1, iC).Address, "$")(1)

        cTeal   = 14
        cPurple = 5

        'set the range address string
        col_letter = col_letter & ":" & col_letter

        'set the range to a single column letter/name for the match function
        set rng = objXLApp.Range(col_letter)

        tRow        = objXLApp.Match(cTeal,rng,-1) 'find the last row for Teal value
        pRow    = objXLApp.Match(cPurple,rng,-1) 'find the row for Purple value
        'Msgbox tRow
        'Msgbox pRow

        objXLApp.Range(objRange.Item(2, iC).Address & ":" & objRange.Item(tRow, iC).Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 42 'Teal 
        objXLApp.Range(objRange.Item(tRow+1, iC).Address & ":" & objRange.Item(pRow, iC).Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 34 'Cyan
        objXLApp.Range(objRange.Item(pRow+1, iC).Address & ":" & objRange.Item(objRange.Item(2, iC).End(xlDown).Row, iC).Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 39 'Purple
    End If
Next
```